# Is there any data structure that holds two keys that points to each other?

Tags: database, string, data-structures, hashmap, character

I was solving a problem and tried to use a HashMap in it, but there is a problem.

Say this is a Hashmap<Character , String> , and it turns to be:

{a=dog ; b=cat ; c=turtle ; d=turtle}

The problem is that I don't want two different Characters pointing at the same String.

And if I suppose a HashMap<String , Character> , then there is another problem

{dog=a ; cat=d ; ; turtle=d}

I don't want 2 different Strings to point at the same character.

How can I find a way to assure that all objects are pointing to different values.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you mean to ask, "Can I have one data structure that allows the keys to point to the same value, but not duplicate the value", is that right?

Comment: It would help me if you added the inputs and the desired outputs in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for a [bidirectional map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_map). I am not aware of languages that have this more esoteric data structure as a built in, but it is implemented in multiple common packages, such as [Apache Commons's BidiMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html) in java